# restsharp get error (authentication)

Tags: authentication, get, restsharp

I have a API GET call that works in postman BUT not in VS2017. I copied the code 
from postman:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://server-    d01:9000/amp/portal/api/dougtest/v1");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("Postman-Token", "19763da3-4b00-4e92-83e0-1ac75f99d219");
request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("X-XSRF-TOKEN", "71cf12361-8090-499a-adc3-2d5e98a04143");
request.AddParameter("undefined", "{\n    \"username\":\"domain\\\\username\",\n    \"password\":\"myPasswd\"\n}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

The error I am getting is unauthorized, the API required a header of `X-XSRF-TOKEN` with a value of `71cf12361-8090-499a-adc3-2d5e98a04143` (a fake key)

Using postman, everything works just fine, but using VS2017 I get an error:

> `{"status":"unauthorized","error":"Login is required","errormsg":null}`

What's weird (I am new to this so pardon my ignorance)is that the header does not contain:

```
request.AddHeader("X-XSRF-TOKEN", "71cf12361-8090-499a-adc3-2d5e98a04143");
```

but rather the parameter does, which is confusing since I thought the `AddHeader` would add it to the header but maybe I am misunderstanding  something....

any advice/suggestions would be extremely welcomed

thank you in advance

dougc

Comment: Can you share the Header which you have added in Postman?

Comment: X-XSRF-TOKEN value of: "c99dc1d1-a8c5-44bf-8174-9ecac2809953  I go the value from a post call and verified the token/key is valid via postman

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code and check

```
var client = new RestClient("http://server-    d01:9000/amp/portal/api/dougtest/v1");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
//Make sure to give the Valid Token
request.AddHeader("Authorization","X-XSRF-TOKEN <<Generated Token>>");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

Console.WriteLine("Response :" + response.Content);
```

Comment: sadly still get the same error:  in postman in the header section I have a key column with X-XSRF-TOKEN and a value column with the token

Comment: If it is possible, Can you please add the POST Man Snapshot with Header information ?

Comment: here is the header from the postman console:   Request Headers:
x-xsrf-token:"7d4b1221-0cb5-4811-9bd-09dcda579e7f"
cache-control:"no-cache"
postman-token:"658ebdf5-b3bb-4c3c-85b6-3a110c235bdb"
user-agent:"PostmanRuntime/7.1.5"
accept:"*/*"
host:"cfapi-d01:9000"
cookie:"AMPSESSIONID=7d4b1221-0cb5-4811-9bd-09dcda579e7f"
accept-encoding:"gzip, deflate"